# Is there any error with local moto server and cognito-idp in boto3 with awssrp?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cognito, moto, srp-protocol

I have a local moto server and am verifying cognito-idp in boto3 with awssrp, but I get an error.

The error message is.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tests/get_token.py", line 71, in <module>
    token_res = get_cognito_token(cognito_user_name, cognito_user_password)
  File "/tests/get_token.py", line 63, in get_cognito_token
    tokens = response.authenticate_user()
  File "/Users/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.9.14/lib/python3.9/site-packages/warrant/aws_srp.py", line 210, in authenticate_user
    tokens = boto_client.respond_to_auth_challenge(
  File "/Users/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.9.14/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 530, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.9.14/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 960, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.UserNotFoundException: An error occurred (UserNotFoundException) when calling the RespondToAuthChallenge operation: User does not exist.
```

The code is as follows.

create user and sign up code no error...
create_user.py

```
import boto3
import json


cognito_client = boto3.client('cognito-idp', region_name="us-east-1", endpoint_url='http://localhost:5000')
response = cognito_client.create_user_pool(
    PoolName='local_pool'
)
# print(response)

cl_pool_id = response['UserPool']['Id']
print(f"response_code:{response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode']}")
print(f"pool_id:{response['UserPool']['Id']}")

create_user_res = cognito_client.create_user_pool_client(
    UserPoolId=cl_pool_id,
    ClientName='local_user7',
    ExplicitAuthFlows=[
        # 'ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',
        # 'CUSTOM_AUTH_FLOW_ONLY',
        # 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
        'ALLOW_ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
        # 'ALLOW_CUSTOM_AUTH',
        'ALLOW_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
        'ALLOW_USER_SRP_AUTH',
        'ALLOW_REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH',
    ],
)
cl_client_id = create_user_res['UserPoolClient']['ClientId']
print(f"client_id:{cl_client_id}")


cognito_user_name = "dummy7"
cognito_user_email = "dummy7@dummy.jp"
cognito_user_password = "P@ssw0rd"

create_user_res = cognito_client.admin_create_user(
    UserPoolId=cl_pool_id,
    Username=cognito_user_name,
    UserAttributes=[
        {
            'Name': 'email',
            'Value': cognito_user_email
        },
        {
            'Name': 'email_verified',
            'Value': "true"
        },
    ],
    MessageAction='SUPPRESS',
)

print(f"create_user_res:{create_user_res}")


set_user_pass = cognito_client.admin_set_user_password(
    UserPoolId=cl_pool_id,
    Username=cognito_user_name,
    Password=cognito_user_password,
    Permanent=True
)

print(f"set_user_pass_res:{set_user_pass}")

list_users = cognito_client.list_users(
    UserPoolId=cl_pool_id,
)

print(f"list_users:{list_users}")


user_pool_client = cognito_client.describe_user_pool_client(
    UserPoolId=cl_pool_id,
    ClientId=cl_client_id,
)
print(f"user_pool_client:{user_pool_client}")
```

authenticate code  with error.
get_token.py

```
import ast
import base64
import boto3
import json
import logging
import os
import re
from warrant.aws_srp import AWSSRP


pool_id = "us-east-1_8d32eabf665f214687c6ba15282a4ad20d36fdae19d630"
client_id = "jp4v9277l6pca2v5ei2v0p5ayh"
cognito_user_name = "dummy7"
cognito_user_email = "dummy7@dummy.jp"
cognito_user_password = "P@ssw0rd"

cognito_client = boto3.client('cognito-idp', region_name="us-east-1", endpoint_url='http://localhost:5000')

def get_cognito_token(username, password):

    response = AWSSRP(
        username=cognito_user_name,
        password=cognito_user_password,
        pool_id=pool_id,
        client_id=client_id,
        client=cognito_client,
    )
    print(f"response:{response}")
    print(f"response_dir:{dir(response)}")
    # print(f"response_vars:{vars(response)}")

    tokens = response.authenticate_user()
    result = tokens["AuthenticationResult"]
    return result

token_res = get_cognito_token(cognito_user_name, cognito_user_password)
print(f"token_res:{token_res}")
```

error I search various things from the contents, but moto server itself seems to support srp as well.
I tried password authentication with moto server, which is not srp, for a user that has already been created, and it authenticated without problems.
I would like to know if anyone has succeeded in mocking with moto server using srp.

Comment: Is the pool ID hardcoded?  (`pool_id = "us-east-1_8d32eabf665f214687c6ba15282a4ad20d36fdae19d630"`) You should use the one returned by Moto instead

Comment: Thank you for comment.
and sorry for not enough info ,  when, execute create_user.py,  i picked up return value pool_id and client_id and change get_token.py every time. so it is  returned by Moto.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar error. Repro below. For me, specifying UsernameAttributes when creating the User Pool (uncommenting the commented line) makes it work.

From the logs, [Warrant is sending the user ID in the challenge response (rather than the username)](https://github.com/capless/warrant/blob/e81f9a6dd6e36be3b6fa1dbbd11334ec92124ace/warrant/aws_srp.py#L191). But it looks like [moto uses admin_get_user](https://github.com/getmoto/moto/blob/50b20b56c4b5fb40584bd88fb564d3999ab721c8/moto/cognitoidp/models.py#L1185) which [is ultimately keyed from the username unless the `UsernameAttributes` are specified](https://github.com/getmoto/moto/blob/50b20b56c4b5fb40584bd88fb564d3999ab721c8/moto/cognitoidp/models.py#L409). Because I'm using the email as the username, this works in my case. But I don't think that works in your case.

I can see from the logs of a production AWSSRP handshake that that is also sending the username in the InitiateAuth but the user ID in the RespondToAuthChallenge. This makes me think that respond_to_auth_challenge in moto isn't quite replicating the API here.

```py
import boto3
import moto
from warrant.aws_srp import AWSSRP


boto3.set_stream_logger("botocore")

mock = moto.mock_cognitoidp()
mock.start()


REGION = "us-east-1"

client = boto3.client("cognito-idp", region_name=REGION)

USER_POOL_ID = client.create_user_pool(
    PoolName="MyPool",
    UsernameConfiguration={
        "CaseSensitive": False,
    },
    # UsernameAttributes=["email"],
)["UserPool"]["Id"]

USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID = client.create_user_pool_client(
    UserPoolId=USER_POOL_ID,
    ClientName="MyClient",
    ExplicitAuthFlows=["ALLOW_USER_SRP_AUTH"],
)["UserPoolClient"]["ClientId"]

USERNAME = "test@example.com"
client.admin_create_user(
    UserPoolId=USER_POOL_ID,
    Username=USERNAME,
    MessageAction="SUPPRESS",
)

PASSWORD = "abc123"
client.admin_set_user_password(
    UserPoolId=USER_POOL_ID,
    Username=USERNAME,
    Password=PASSWORD,
    Permanent=True,
)

srp = AWSSRP(
    username=USERNAME,
    password=PASSWORD,
    pool_id=USER_POOL_ID,
    client_id=USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID,
    client=client,
)

srp.authenticate_user()
```